# Does convergence of $\sqrt{n}X_n$ to $N(0,1)$ in distribution implies $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

This question stems from the WLLN and the Central Limit Theorem. Suppose we have $n$ iid random samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ with common mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$. Then the sample mean $\bar{X}$ has variance $\sigma^2/n$ which tends to zero allowing $\bar{X}\rightarrow \mu$ in probability, at the same time we also have $$\sqrt{n}\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\rightarrow N(0,1)$$ in distribution by the central limit theorem. My question sort of concerns moving from CLT to the WLLN, namely let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, not necessarily independent. Suppose $\sqrt{n}X_n \rightarrow N(0,1)$ in distribution, can we conclude that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

My attempt: We have $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\leq \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(-\varepsilon\leq X_n\leq \varepsilon) =\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{n}\varepsilon\leq \sqrt{n}X_n\leq \sqrt{n}\varepsilon),$$
now we have $$ \mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{n}\varepsilon\leq \sqrt{n}X_n\leq \sqrt{n}\varepsilon)=\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}X_n \leq \sqrt{n}\varepsilon) - \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}X_n\leq -\sqrt{n}\varepsilon),$$
but $\sqrt{n}X_n$ converges to $N(0,1)$, and so we have $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}X_n \leq \sqrt{n}\varepsilon) \rightarrow \Phi(\sqrt{n}\varepsilon)\rightarrow1$ and similarly $\mathbb{P}(\sqrt{n}X_n\leq -\sqrt{n}\varepsilon) \rightarrow 0$, so we can conclude that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\leq \varepsilon) \rightarrow 1$ for any $\varepsilon$.

Can someone comment on it?

Comment: This seems correct to me.

Comment: Indeed, $X_n=\sqrt n X_n \cdot \frac1{\sqrt n}$ converges in probability to $0$ by Slutsky's theorem.